# Trying to view instance data of an object through a different class

Tags: java, class, instance, instanceof

I have a program where I have four objects of class `Programmer` along with some other classes that all inherit my parent class, `Employee`.

So in my main method I store these `Employee` objects in an `ArrayList`. The main instance data for the `Programmer` class is 'technologies' and it holds the Strings for the various technologies they know. Such as, 'SQL', 'Java', 'Python'... ect.

Well I am stuck because I need to identify how many of my programmers know Java and add up their individual incomes etc. But, of course when I am looping through my `Employee ArrayList`...

```
            for (Employee e : staff)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        salaryTotal += e.getSalary();
        if (e instanceof Programmer){
            programmerStaff++;
            if (e.technologies.contains("Java")){
            }
        }
    }
```

it looks for the instance data 'technologies' in my `Employee` class, how can I get it to look at the object's instantiated class, after I have determined e instanceof `Programmer`?

I also tried using an access method but it would just look for said method in `Employee`

Comment: If you have an `ArrayList` that can contain any kind of `Employee` (i.e. an `ArrayList<Employee>`, then the only way to handle an element drawn from that array as an instance of a subclass of `Employee` is to downcast: `Programmer p = (Programmer)e;`.  Guarding that with an `instanceof` test will ensure that the cast succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast it to `Programmer`:

```
if (((Programmer) e).technologies.contains("Java"))
```

We've added `(Programmer) e` in parentheses because if not, it will try to cast what the `contains` method returns (in this case a boolean) into a `Programmer`.

You can also do:

```
Programmer programmer = (Programmer) e;
```

Not all types can be casted to another certain type, so checking with `instanceof` is a good practice to avoid a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

Comment: ahah, yes. I just came back because I figured that out after staring at it for awhile and was going to post this.

Thank you so much for your contribution, though!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Doing it the way you are doing it you could just cast it.

```
for (Employee e : staff){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    salaryTotal += e.getSalary();
    if (e instanceof Programmer){
        programmerStaff++;
        Programmer p = (Programmer) e
        if (p.technologies.contains("Java")){
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not a fan of this technique. I think it's confusing logically (why should your method care that only programmers know programming languages? Why do you have to know what subclass you have? It's just messy) and ugly ascetically.

I would instead move some of the functionality to the superclass. Have a method `knowsLanguage(String language)` in Employee. Then you return false for the classes that never know any programming languages, and true/false for the programmers.

You could also change the instanceOf to use a similar technique. `knowsProgramming()` is cleaner in my head (and you can add other programmer classes without problems, maybe you want to have programmer/designers in one class later on)

Comment: Moving subclass-specific functionality to the base class is a code smell. And if you have an accountant who happens to know Java, how are you going to satisfy OP's requirement to "identify how many of my **programmers** know Java"? Perhaps you'll then add a method `isProgrammer()`? Are you going to keep expanding the base class for every `Employee` subtype that gets added to the system?